# Conservation laws for modified Degasperis-Procesi equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stability, conservation-laws

It is known that the Korteweg-de Vries equation
$$u_{t}+uu_{x}+u_{xxx} = 0,$$
with $u=u(x,t)$ smooth and with period equal to $L$, has important conservation laws, namely,
$$E(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L} u_{x}^{2} - \frac{1}{3}u^{3}\ dx\ \ \text{and}\ \ F(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L}u^{2}\ dx.$$

$E$ and $F$ are independent of the temporal variable $t$.

It is also knoun that the Degasperis-Procesi equation
$$u_{t}-u_{xxt} = uu_{xxx}+3u_{x}u_{xx}-4u u_{x}$$
has a infinite number of conservation laws.

> **Question:** Are there conservation laws for modified Degasperis-Procesi equation
>   $$u_{t}-u_{xxt} = uu_{xxx}+3u_{x}u_{xx}-4u^{2}u_{x}\ \ ?$$

Comment: I think the question is not very clear as written. What are "the properties above" in your question? Could you please state them more precisely?

Comment: ... and please write the _equation_ with $u_{xxx}$ and $=0$ ?